# How can I make a dictionary out of consecutive elements in a list?

Tags: python

Lets say I have the list `numbers = ['Joe', '123-5432', 'Linda', '983-4123', 'Frank', '867-5309']`. How can I make a dictionary out of the list that associates an element with the next one? So I can end up with something like `phones = {'Joe': '123-5432', 'Linda' : '983-4123', 'Frank' : '867-5309'}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```py
numbers = ['Joe', '123-5432', 'Linda', '983-4123', 'Frank', '867-5309']
d = {numbers[i]:numbers[i+1] for i in range(0, len(numbers), 2)}
print(d)
```

```
{'Joe': '123-5432', 'Linda': '983-4123', 'Frank': '867-5309'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = ['Joe', '123-5432', 'Linda', '983-4123', 'Frank', '867-5309']
newDict = {}
for i in range(0, len(numbers), 2):
    newDict[numbers[i]] = numbers[i+1]
```

I'm iterating over the length of the array but in the steps of 2 so that I can access the list element with the current iteration index and the next iteration.